# How to locate a NAV with position:fixed; at the center?

Tags: html, css-position, fixed

The nav is floating to the left when I assign its position to fixed.
How do I move it back to the center?

```
.container {
        max-width: 2000px;
        text-align: center;
        color: rgb(177, 177, 179);
    }

nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        position: fixed; 
    }
```

I want to fix the Navbar at the center. 
But when I assign the Navbar position to fixed it is floating to the left side.

Here's the image: [image]

Comment: Can you add whole code with HTML?
Or same case in JSfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4768fje0/

Comment: Can you check for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS's left & right property.

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning

Answer (score 0):

Add Width 100% to nav
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/1826szqm/1/

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```